# How to create new folder type for Windows 10 explorer

Tags: windows, directory, explorer

How to create new folder type for  Windows 10 explorer

The folder type embedded are  : (General Items, Documents, Pictures, Music, Video )

I'd like to add : message, video 2 , aso ...
.
I found Nothing in regedit
I found *Nothing by Google

Comment: Probably you have some restrictions for Google usage... First search result give me the manufacturer's article: [Windows libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/client-tools/windows-libraries)